# Can I request new ad from onAdFailedToLoad?

Tags: android, admob

During testing of my application, I noticed that I very frequently get ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL for Interstitial Ad. I think that the same situation with real ads might be one of the causes of low income from the application, so I want to increase the rate of showed ads. As the solution, I decided to make requests until I will get some app, so it might take from 5 to 50 requests until I will get out of onAdFailedToLoad. Is it a legitimate way to do this? Won't I get banned by AdMob with such way of getting more ads?

That's what I do in setAdListener in onCreate:

```
 @Override
 public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
     requestNewInterstitial();
 }
```

And requestNewInterstitial():

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't get banned...

You can do this, but don't show the Ad as soon it is loaded, this will be a bombarding of Ads & user won't like that...

Comment: That is the problem actually. I show the add only at some levels, where I decided from user reviews the ads are not that disturbing. And then I do the request only once, and if I don't get the ad, the next time will be not soon. So users left without ads, which is great for them... Not that great for me though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ЕкатеринаЛевченко you can always check like `mInterstitial.isLoaded()`, if true > show() else load/wait... If the answer helped, please accept it :)